# NGit (JGit port) authentication with SSH on C#

Tags: c#, git, ssh, jgit, ngit

I'm tyring to setup Git functionality in my application with NGit. The repository is an SSH authenticated one on BitBucket, that I am unable to authenticate for Git functionality like Push, Pull, Clone etc.

My code is as follows:

**JschConfigSessionFactory:**

```
public class NSessionFactory : JschConfigSessionFactory
{
    protected override void Configure(OpenSshConfig.Host hc, Session session)
    {
        session.SetConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    }

    protected override JSch CreateDefaultJSch(FS fs)
    {
        JSch defaultJSch = new JSch();
        defaultJSch.SetKnownHosts(@"<path>\known_hosts");
        defaultJSch.AddIdentity(@"<path>\id_rsa");
        return defaultJSch;
    }
}
```

**TransportConfigCallback:**

```
public class NTransportConfigCallBack : TransportConfigCallback
{
    public void Configure(Transport transport)
    {
        SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport)transport;
        sshTransport.SetSshSessionFactory(new NSessionFactory());
    }
}
```

**Push command:**

```
Git gitObj = NGit.Api.Git.Open(<path to git repo>);

PushCommand pshCmd = gitObj.Push();
pshCmd.SetRemote("ssh://git@stash.name.com:xxxx/repo.git");
pshCmd.SetTransportConfigCallback(new NTransportConfigCallBack());
pshCmd.Call();
```

**Following exception on PushCommand.Call():**

```
"TransportException: ssh://git@stash.name.com:xxxx/repo.git: Auth fail"
```

The BitBucket account already has the SSH key setup and everything works with other GIT tools.

At this point I have no idea what could be wrong, and I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

*Using C# on Visual Studio 2017 with .Net 4.5.2*

## **EDIT 1**

Changing up the code as in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764435/ngit-making-a-connection-with-a-private-key-file) produces the same exception.

Comment: Does your remote URL have the right format? It seems that for public BitBucket repositories it would be `ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<username>/repo.git`. Can you connect to the repository with CLI Git?

Comment: The URL is correct, and I have already used the same to clone the repository. See here: http://imgur.com/a/JhW02

I'm using the same url in my code. Really don't think that's the problem :(

Comment: It seems that your ssh key requires a passphrase, in this case, use `defaultJsch.addIdentity( "<path>", "<passphrase>" )`.

Comment: Ah that was it! Thanks for the tip Rüdiger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your SSH key requires a passphrase, in this case, use

```
defaultJsch.AddIdentity( "<path>", "<passphrase>" )
```